# Essbase Error 1242021- while executing Maxl to run a report script

Tags: essbase

I am running a Maxl to export database using report script, below is the Maxl:

```
spool stdout on to "$4Adhoc.mxl.log";
spool stderr on to "$9Adhoc.mxl.err";

alter system load application $5;
alter application $5 load database $6

export database $5.$6 using report_file "\\scripts\\report\\Adhoc.rep" to data_file "\\abc1234.com\\xyz\\files\\Man7\\Adhoc$11.txt";
logout;
exit;
```

I keep getting the following error:
ERROR - 1242021 - (3) Syntax error near ['export'].
Please advise what is missing in this syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a semi colon on the preceding line.

Comment: Thanks @Jwj, I figured that out after I wrote my query here but then I'm getting Error1241109-Unable to open File [\\abc1234.com\\xyz\\files\\Man7\\Adhoc$11.txt'].

Comment: figured it out, just need an extra backslash [\\\abc1234.com\\xyz\\files\\Man7\\Adhoc$11.txt.Thanks @jwj

Comment: You should typically put in four backslashes in that case, instead of three. Three technically works but when defining a UNC path/share drive path inside of a double-quoted string, you would have four, which "results" in two after the string is evaluated.

Comment: Oh Okay.Thanks lot @jwj

Comment: You're welcome. Please don't forget to mark answers as helpful by upvoting them.